# Example DataTable - Selection from Primefaces can't be compiled

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a problem implementing example of DataTable - Selection from Primefaces website: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

I created two classes as described: `SelectionView.java and CarService.java`, however my Netbeans 8.0.1 shows error in class:

> SelectionView.java: package import org.primefaces.showcase.domain.Car
>   does not exist package import
>   org.primefaces.showcase.service.CarService does not exist

Same in CarService.java:

> package import org.primefaces.showcase.domain.Car does not exist

However similar imports like:

```
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.UnselectEvent;
```

Works fine.

A am using Netbeans 8.0.1 and buiilt in library of Primefaces 5.0.

Here is the code:
**SelectionView.java**

```
package main;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.UnselectEvent;
import org.primefaces.showcase.domain.Car;
import org.primefaces.showcase.service.CarService;

@ManagedBean(name="dtSelectionView")
@ViewScoped
public class SelectionView implements Serializable {

    private List<Car> cars1;
    private List<Car> cars2;
    private List<Car> cars3;
    private List<Car> cars4;
    private List<Car> cars5;
    private List<Car> cars6;
    private Car selectedCar;
    private List<Car> selectedCars;

    @ManagedProperty("#{carService}")
    private CarService service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        cars1 = service.createCars(10);
        cars2 = service.createCars(10);
        cars3 = service.createCars(10);
        cars4 = service.createCars(10);
        cars5 = service.createCars(10);
        cars6 = service.createCars(10);
    }

    public List<Car> getCars1() {
        return cars1;
    }

    public List<Car> getCars2() {
        return cars2;
    }

    public List<Car> getCars3() {
        return cars3;
    }

    public List<Car> getCars4() {
        return cars4;
    }

    public List<Car> getCars5() {
        return cars5;
    }

    public List<Car> getCars6() {
        return cars6;
    }

    public void setService(CarService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public Car getSelectedCar() {
        return selectedCar;
    }

    public void setSelectedCar(Car selectedCar) {
        this.selectedCar = selectedCar;
    }

    public List<Car> getSelectedCars() {
        return selectedCars;
    }

    public void setSelectedCars(List<Car> selectedCars) {
        this.selectedCars = selectedCars;
    }

    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Car Selected", ((Car) event.getObject()).getId());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    public void onRowUnselect(UnselectEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Car Unselected", ((Car) event.getObject()).getId());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
}
```

**CarService.java**

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import org.primefaces.showcase.domain.Car;

@ManagedBean(name = "carService")
@ApplicationScoped
public class CarService {

    private final static String[] colors;

    private final static String[] brands;

    static {
        colors = new String[10];
        colors[0] = "Black";
        colors[1] = "White";
        colors[2] = "Green";
        colors[3] = "Red";
        colors[4] = "Blue";
        colors[5] = "Orange";
        colors[6] = "Silver";
        colors[7] = "Yellow";
        colors[8] = "Brown";
        colors[9] = "Maroon";

        brands = new String[10];
        brands[0] = "BMW";
        brands[1] = "Mercedes";
        brands[2] = "Volvo";
        brands[3] = "Audi";
        brands[4] = "Renault";
        brands[5] = "Fiat";
        brands[6] = "Volkswagen";
        brands[7] = "Honda";
        brands[8] = "Jaguar";
        brands[9] = "Ford";
    }

    public List<Car> createCars(int size) {
        List<Car> list = new ArrayList<Car>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
            list.add(new Car(getRandomId(), getRandomBrand(), getRandomYear(), getRandomColor(), getRandomPrice(), getRandomSoldState()));
        }

        return list;
    }

    private String getRandomId() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8);
    }

    private int getRandomYear() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1960);
    }

    private String getRandomColor() {
        return colors[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];
    }

    private String getRandomBrand() {
        return brands[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];
    }

    public int getRandomPrice() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 100000);
    }

    public boolean getRandomSoldState() {
        return (Math.random() > 0.5) ? true: false;
    }

    public List<String> getColors() {
        return Arrays.asList(colors);
    }

    public List<String> getBrands() {
        return Arrays.asList(brands);
    }
}
```

Any ideas? :(

Thanks!

Comment: Change the Package to org.primefaces.showcase.service instead of simply main or change the import to main.CarService?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to import classes from the primefaces showcase:

```
import org.primefaces.showcase.domain.Car;
import org.primefaces.showcase.service.CarService;
```

Those are not available in your project.. Remove the 2 imports.

Comment: I got that. The problem is that if I remove them, "car" became unknown type. This entire example built on showcase. Currently I am looking how to import them into a project.

Comment: import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent; 
import org.primefaces.event.UnselectEvent;

Those are part of the primefaces .jar package and therefore are available. 

Car and CarService are not part of the primefaces package. Those are just examples to illustrate how primefaces work. You do not import those, but you make your own...